# Minimal Squid proxy configuration doesn't work

Tags: debian, squid

I have been trying in vain for the past few days to set-up a Squid3 proxy on my Debian box. I have done the usual stuff of install the software, adding in the config etc. My config looks like:

```
acl localhost src 127.0.0.1/32 ::1
acl to_localhost dst 127.0.0.0/8 0.0.0.0/32 ::1
http_access allow localhost
http_port 50001
http_access allow all
```

The squid proxy is listening on the proper port as per `netstat`.

```
me@vps:/etc/squid3$ netstat -l
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp6       0      0 [::]:50001              [::]:*                  LISTEN
```

The access logs look something like this:

```
1404520356.673  60499 X.X.129.122 TCP_MISS/503 0 CONNECT mail.google.com:443 - DIRECT/2607:f8b0:4004:803::1015 -
1404520416.716  59876 X.X.129.122 TCP_MISS/503 0 CONNECT mail.google.com:443 - DIRECT/2607:f8b0:4004:803::1015 -
1404520431.727 182508 X.X.129.122 TCP_MISS/504 4816 GET http://www.google.com/ - DIRECT/2607:f8b0:4004:803::1010 text/html
1404520476.758  59885 X.X.129.122 TCP_MISS/503 0 CONNECT mail.google.com:443 - DIRECT/2607:f8b0:4004:803::1015 -
1404520536.798  59884 X.X.129.122 TCP_MISS/503 0 CONNECT mail.google.com:443 - DIRECT/2607:f8b0:4004:803::1015 -
1404520596.588  59633 X.X.129.122 TCP_MISS/503 0 CONNECT mail.google.com:443 - DIRECT/2607:f8b0:4004:803::1015 -
```

The error I get when using my proxy in Firefox is:

> The requested URL could not be retrieved The system returned: (110)
>   Connection timed out The remote host or network may be down. Please
>   try the request again.

Would appreciate any pointers/help on this. Thanks.

**EDIT 1**: It's interesting that I can connect to google/yahoo/facebook from my VPS but not some other websites like `whatsmyip.org`.

Comment: Is the server running your squid proxy itself behind another proxy? It is clear that it does not have outgoing Internet connectivity.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: Very interesting; I am able to `wget` websites like google/yahoo/facebook on my VPS but can't get it to work for `whatsmyip.org`...

Comment: OK so don't think outgoing connections are a problem because I can access google.com just fine on my VPS but not when I'm using the proxy on that VPS.

Comment: Is this machine properly configured for IPv6?  You are attempting to connect to an IPv6 address.  `DIRECT/2607:f8b0:4004:803::1015`

Comment: @Zoredache: I'm not very sure, but then again, I really don't need IPv6. Is there a way of ensuring Squid uses IPv4?

Comment: try: http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/dns_v4_first/

Comment: @Zoredache: Awesome stuff; that one line worked like a charm, thanks a lot! Please post as answer and I'll upvote + accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in looking at your logs we can pretty clearly see that your system is attempting to use an IPv6 address for mail.google.com (`DIRECT/2607:f8b0:4004:803::1015`).  This would happen if you have an IPv6 somewhat configured on your system.

But I suspect you don't have it completely configured, or perhaps your ISP doesn't have IPv6 fully configured.  The point is IPv6 is broken somewhere between you and Google.

You could completely disabled IPv6 or spend the time to fix it.  But lets just ignore that for now.

As a short term fix you can change a setting in squid to always use an IPv4 address first if there is one available for a given name.  Just [set](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/dns_v4_first/) `dns_v4_first on` in your squid configuration.

Unrelated to your Squid problem, if this is a Linux box you may also want to take a look at your local `gai.conf`.  This isn't used by squid, but this is used by your OS for configuring name resolution.  You may want to set, or un-comment the line `precedence ::ffff:0:0/96  100` to prefer IPv4 over IPv6 for the rest of your system.